# GFCI Test button is intermittent

Tags: gfci

I put in a new GFCI outlet (Electeck model GF-15-WT-5PK), but my TEST button is intermittent. It takes 2-4 presses to trip it off. There was no issue before I mounted it to the wall. Initially it would trip immediately when I flipped the circuit breaker on, but I fixed that by tightening the ground.

When the outlet is hanging by the wires, it tested on the first press.

I tried my fingers and a screwdriver and it does not trip off on the first press of the TEST button.

The outlet is installed in a Wiremold metal deep extender box. Wiremold backplate is grounded.

Comment: Model #? Is there any indicator light when it is on but not tripped? Do regular loads (lamp, radio, etc.) work when it is not tripped? If you take it out (hanging by the wires) does it go back to test working correctly?

Comment: What make and model is the GFCI? Does pulling it back out cause the TEST button to work correctly again?

Comment: Electeck GF-15-WT-5PK. Pulling it back out causes the TEST button to work correctly again.

Comment: The TEST button was working correctly when it was pulled out, now it doesn’t work after pulling it out a couple of more times.

Comment: Very strange. The Electeck products claim UTL or ETL listing, but are almost exclusively on Amazon and similar sites. Information on those sites borders on Chinglish. Not sure whether they're "good" or not.

Comment: I’m trying a different GFCI in my pack, but I have a feeling it won’t change anything.

Comment: I got it to work, I used a new GFCI with a new ground routing. I had my ground jumper to my GFCI and a separate jumper to the backplate of the Wiremold. I initially had the ground go to the GFCI and then to the backplate.

Comment: @Jumbojoe55 please post that as an answer, not a comment, then, once the system allows it, click the check mark to accept the answer. That way, others with similar problems will know that this one has a working solution.

Answer (score 3):

### Those are counterfeit GFCIs

I would chide you for being "cheap", but the fact is, many of the dangerous or [counterfeit items](https://www.washingtonpost.com/technology/2019/11/14/how-amazons-quest-more-cheaper-products-has-resulted-flea-market-fakes/) on Amazon **are being priced same as quality items**.  Further, counterfeiters have [found an exploit](https://www.redpoints.com/blog/amazon-commingled-inventory-management/) that gives you a fake even if you order a "Ships from and sold by Amazon" item.

As a result, **do not buy electrical equipment on Amazon**..... and I gather I don't need to tell you not to buy it on the other shady mail-order sites like eBay, Banggood, DealExtreme, Wish, etc.

Jeff Bezos is firmly committed to making Amazon a "platform to connect sellers to buyers" - in other words, eBay. Further, Bezos has thrown open Amazon's warehousing/fulfillment/delivery system wide open to any comer.  Industries use it, eBay sellers use it, and if the item is also sold on Amazon, it ships with Prime.

So it's a gory mess, and it's impossible to give any guidance as to *how* to buy on Amazon safely.  Best advice: *don't*.

### They all need to be ripped out

.... sent back and replaced with ones from a competent home store.  **Send. Them. Back. Don't you dare let the counterfeiter keep your money!** I know most consumers don't bother with refunds in most cases, but please do with counterfeits - it deters counterfeiters and helps Amazon identify the bad guys.  If the return window has expired, call up Amazon - they're more reachable than you'd think, and yell and scream - you'll get it.

If you don't want to walk into a Home Depot, they and Lowes do curbside pickup, and both will happily mail-order for you, and they ship it from their own supply chain, which *are* under quality controls.

because aside from being unsafe, they're not legal. NEC 110.2, equipment must be *approved*.